# HQL query for Association

Tags: hql

I am having below tables here but having some problem while fetching results.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_VW")
public class WorkspaceUserImpl
{
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = UserImpl.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private User user;

}

@Table(name = "IK_USER")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "USER_ID") )


    public class UserImpl extends BaseAuditable<UserIdentifier>implements User, UserAuthentication {

        private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserImpl.class);

        @Id
        @Type(type = "com.commons.UserIdentifierTypeMapper")
        @Column(name = "USER_ID")
        private UserIdentifier id;
    }
```

and User

```
Public Inteface User
{
      UserIdentifier getId();
}
```

Now i have written an HQL query to fetch all the data from WorkspaceUserImpl class with a given user ID for UserImpl class like below.

```
SELECT w from WorkspaceUserImpl w where w.user.id = : user_id;
```

and also tried

```
SELECT w from WorkspaceUserImpl as w INNER JOIN w.user as u where u.id = : user_id;
```

and even tried with JOIN FETCH also

and setting the parameter **user_id** with some say 1234.

but am getting List as emply for the partcular ID but in DB its having 5 records.

am i making any query mistake here? kindly advice..

Comment: I believe you will need a class called `User` proper to which Hibernate can join `WorkspaceUserImpl`.  Implementing `User` is not sufficient.

Comment: As its a old code i am not permitted to do any modifications in the hirarchy... how abt my HQL?? is it correct what i have done?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below query:

```
from WorkspaceUserImpl as w JOIN FETCH w.user as u where u.id = : user_id;
```